# Symfony - Two same routes with different access control

Tags: symfony, authentication, controller, routes

I have an index page that looks completely different for an authenticated and an unauthenticated user. Is it possible to create two seperate controllers with the same route path ("/") but one will be served only to users that are logged in and the other one only to guests?

Using:

- Symfony 5
- PHP 7.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is a reference to two different methods that return a Response, and return that Response from your routed method.

```
/**
 * @Route("/")
 * @return Response
 */
public function index(): Response
{
    if (/*user is logged logic*/) {
        return $this->indexLogged();
    } else {
        return $this->indexAnonymous();
    }
}

private function indexLogged(): Response
{
    return new Response();
}

private function indexAnonymous(): Response
{
    return new Response();
}
```

Whether indexLogged and indexAnonymous are public or private, have routes or not depends on what you really want, but this would allow you to have shorter functions with only what's needed in each of those.

Answer (score 2):

Having two identical routes is not possible anywhere (unless they have different methods allowed). Depending on your other project requirements what you can do is create a service that loads different views (with different data if needed) depending on user authentication. For a simpler example you can check if the user is logged in in your controller index function and return a different response in each case.

Comment: Yes, I would personally most likely just check within the controller and deliver a different view.